# Parse vcard with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Ruby on Rails app which handles contacts. Now I want to give users the possibility to drag and drop cards on the page and create a contact this way.

By using the HTML5 file API I get the vcard contents in Javascript. So I thought: why even send a request to the server, why not parse it n Javascript?

Unfortunately I can't find a library which does this. Can't be too hard? Any ideas? I would really prefer this solution for simplicity and less hassle on the server side...

Thanks a lot, 
Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done a quick serch for [js vcard](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=js%20vcard&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and found [this vcard.js script](https://github.com/mattt/vcard.js). Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it does help, seems to be great! Thanks a lot! Kind of embarrassed, that I haven't found it...

Comment: The [link](https://github.com/mattt/vcard.js) is dead now. This is why link-only answers are BAD.

Comment: @stribizhev how about googling vcard.js? Or maybe I should have posted the source code of the library in here?

Comment: No, not the source, just the example usage.

Answer (score 0):

A project of mines: https://github.com/ProfessioneIT/jsvcard

I hope it's useful because part of the project was devoted to a platform independent vCard parser written in Javascript. It also solves some encoding problems you normally find when you want to read a vCard.

EDIT: btw. the link from Spadar Shut is now broken (03.06.2015)

Answer (score 0):

Since the link in the original answer is broken, I created this Js library to parse Vcards in Json:

[vCard-Json.js](https://github.com/jeankassio/vCard-Json.js)